# How to process search results using regex?

Tags: regex

How to process search results using regex?

E.g., I have a file with many strings like `AB`.
I want to get: `'AB'`.
The letters always differ.
So I would search for the regex pattern `^\w+\n` and want to use the search result, let me use '$@' to depict it, to get `'$@'`.

Comment: Different programming languages and text editors have different ways of doing this. There isn't a general answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
(?<=:)([^,]+)
```

REplacement string:

```
'$1'
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cE4kK2/1)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise enough. The strings looks like this: `71:A,72:BC,73:ABD` and I want to get `71:'A',72:'BC',73:'ABD'`. In such a case, the substitution doesn't work.

Comment: sorry , could you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: That was just an inadvertent enter :).

Comment: It works 95% fine. What I got was (excerpt): `51:B",52:"C",53:"B",54:"D",55:"A

61:C",62:"B",63:"D",64:"A",65:"AB",66:"C",67:"D

71:A",72:"B",73:"A ` - note the lacking `"` at the beginning and end of each string. In this case the data was small enough to fine that manually, but with larger data this would be an issue.

Comment: I changed to (?<=:)([^(,|\n)]+) and works great now :)

Comment: SORRY IM FROM MOBILE: PUT ONLY COMMA AND NEW LINE CHARACTER INSIDE THAT NEGATED CHARACTER CLASS

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify: You want `71:A,72:BC,73:ABD` to become `71:'A',72:'BC',73:'ABD'` right?

Do a find/replace in whatever language or program you are using:

Find: `(\w+)`
Replace: `'$1'`

This finds ANY multi-letter string in your file and puts ' around it. if you only want to do the ones with `[number:string]` you will need to use a look-ahead like `(?=\d+:)` in front of the `(\w+)`. So the whole Find would then look like `(?=\d+:)(\w+)`, similar to what Avinash Raj has posted.